# AngularJS ng-submitted class removing of form after submit not working with setPrestine and setUntouched

Tags: angularjs

By default Angular adds the class `ng-submitted` to the form that is submitted.

I found out that I had to do some `$setPrestine` and `$setUntouched` on the form itself. But it never works.
Get errors like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPrestine' of undefined
>   TypeError: newFoobarForm.$setPresentine is not a function

```
$scope.submitForm = function(input)
{
    $http.post('/foobar/', input)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            // I wanna reset the state
            // Removing "ng-submitted" from the <form>

            $scope.newFoobarForm.$setPrestine();
            $scope.newFoobarForm.$setUntouched();

            newFoobarForm.$setPrestine();
            newFoobarForm.$setUntouched();
            // All above options test, none worked.

        });    
}

<form ng-submit="submitForm(new)" name="newFoobarForm" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This a a working solution

```
$timeout(function () {
    var i;
    var allForms;
    allForms=document.forms;
    for(i=0;i <allForms.length; i++)
    {
        allForms[i].classList.remove('ng-submitted');
    }
}, 100);
```